# Do browser sessions cookies expire when a window is closed if there is no expiration value set?

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-browser, cross-platform, ttl

I realize there is a difference between a browser closing and a window closing. And it is well documented that a browser being formally 'quit' will clear a cookie that has no set expiration value.

However, depending on the OS and Browser the threshold for what user actions constitute 'quiting' the browser application likely varies.

I've seen some similar questions, but none of the answers really discuss the nuance of cross OS/Browser behavior for cookies in detail, and the potential impacts on UX.

There is a related question posted here touches on firefox behavior, but none of the answers are OS specific or include any details outside of possible firefox behavior.

[Do session cookies expire when the browser is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869271/do-session-cookies-expire-when-the-browser-is-closed)